# Inverse of equation with Legendre polynomials

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, multipole-expansion

I have to find the inverse of the equation of the multipole moment of a field
\begin{equation}
\Theta_l(k)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{d\mu}{2}\mathcal{P}_l(\mu)\Theta(k,\mu),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{P}_l(\mu)$ is the Legendre polynomial of order $l$, in order to have an equation for $\Theta$. The result on my book (Modern Cosmology by Scott Dodelson) is the following
\begin{equation}
\Theta(k,\mu)=\sum_l(-i)^l(2l+1)\mathcal{P}_l(\mu)\Theta_l(k).
\end{equation}
where $\mu=\vec{k}\cdot\hat{p}$.

I want to derive the second equation starting from the first one.
I guess that I have to use the completeness relation of the Legendre polynomials bit I don't know how.

Comment: The two equations you have already appear to be inverses.   Could you be more explicit about what you are looking for?

Comment: @Buzz Yes I know that both equations are one the inverse of the other. But my question is about how to derive the second one starting from the first one. Thanks